# How to use sp_MSforeachtable to update a column which is present in all tables of a database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a column in each table which holds flag value as 'N' if data in the row is erroneous. This flag column gets updated by running a validation script. I need to set these columns to 'Y' before I run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'UPDATE ? SET YourColumn = ''Y'''
```